# What is the path of libraries (samples, docs) setted up from Software Center of Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-center, libraries, opencv

I installed OpenCV and its DOC and Samples from software center but I cannot find the them at anywhere. What is the certain location for all these at Ubuntu12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to issue the list-files option of dpkg from a terminal.

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Enter the following command:
   `dpkg --listfiles opencv-doc`

You can also find the information from Synaptic Package Manager, if you prefer a GUI, but you'll have to install synaptic from the Ubuntu Software Centre first.